# EE Search Categories

Tags: search, tags, simple-search

EE 5.2.6

Is there any way to use the simple or advanced search forms native to EE to search categories as well as channels?

I see that there's a [category parameter](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/add-ons/search/advanced.html#category) but I'm not really sure what is the point of it.

I'm not really looking for anything fancy, just wondering of categories can be queried in the native search functionality.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can't search categories using inbuilt search. The advanced search form uses categories so you can refine your search query, i.e. search for keyword "blue" in the "products" category.

If you specifically needed to search category data then you'll need a 3rd party addon such as https://gotolow.com/addons/low-search